# How do you fix: "AttributeError: 'SpriteSheet' object has no attribute 'set_colorkey'"?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, python-3.7

I am importing a background image for my game, but I keep getting this error:

```
"File "/Users//PycharmProjects/Platformer/levels.py", line 75, in __init__
self.background.set_colorkey(constants.WHITE)
AttributeError: 'SpriteSheet' object has no attribute 'set_colorkey'".
```

I have imported a file named `spritesheet_functions.py` to the file I'm using. However, I'm sure I had a `set_colorkey` command in my `SpriteSheet` class, so can anyone fix this?

```
import pygame
from os import path
import constants

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'IMG')


class SpriteSheet(object):
    """ Class used to grab images out of a sprite sheet. """

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        """ Constructor. Pass in the file name of the sprite sheet. """

        # Load the sprite sheet.
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(path.join(img_dir, 
                                             file_name)).convert()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        """ Grab a single image out of a larger spritesheet
             Pass in the x, y location of the sprite
            and the width and height of the sprite. """

        # Create a new blank image
        image = pygame.Surface([width, height]).convert()

        # Copy the sprite from the large sheet onto the smaller image
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))

        # Assuming black works as the transparent color
        image.set_colorkey(constants.BLACK)

        # Return the image
        return image


class Level01(Level):
     """ Definition for level 1. """

     def __init__(self, player):
    """ Create level 1. """

        # Call the parent constructor
        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.background = SpriteSheet('background_01.png')
        self.background.set_colorkey(constants.WHITE)
        self.level_limit = -2500
```

Comment: Is the file  `p1_walk.png` in a location that's accessible to your running code?  Is it a valid PNG image file (not corrupt, empty, etc.) ?  My guess is the file is missing.

Comment: I wrote the full message.

Comment: instead of coping image in `get_image` you can use [Surface.subsurface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface)

Comment: Frankly, it is not full message. Full message starts at word "Traceback". But it is enought to see which line of code made problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `set_colorkey` in wrong way in

```
self.background = SpriteSheet('background_01.png')
self.background.set_colorkey(constants.WHITE)
```

Full error message should show it.

`self.background` is instance of class `SpriteSheet`, not `Surface` which has `set_colorkey`

Probably you have to use `set_colorkey` on `SpriteSheet.sprite_sheet` which is a `Surface`

```
self.background.sprite_sheet.set_colorkey(constants.WHITE)
```